# How to Trigger a followup intent when user clicks on a dialogflow button link

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have used the dialogflow one click integration for telegram. how can i trigger a follow up intent when a user clicks on a button link that redirects to an external site?

```
  agent.add(
      new Card({
        title: `Please click the link below and input your Password.`,
        buttonText: "Click to input your password",
        buttonUrl: "https://password.com/",
        meta: "run intent"

      })
    );
```

I added a meta key, but this did not work.

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution for this?